# Are nested cursors in SQL Server possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Is it possible to write nested cursors in SQL Server?

I have something like this, but it goes into an infinite loop; the below code is used to go through all the columns of every table found in a database.

```
declare @tbl_name varchar(100)
declare @cl_name varchar(200)

declare Crs_tbl CURSOR FOR
select t.name
from sys.tables t

open Crs_tbl
fetch next from Crs_tbl into @tbl_name
while @@fetch_status=0
begin


declare Crs_columns CURSOR FOR
select c.name 
from sys.columns c
where c.object_id=(select object_id from sys.tables where name=@tbl_name)

open Crs_columns
fetch next from Crs_columns into @cl_name
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
begin

--check if value found on current column; if yes, store table and column information


close Crs_columns
Deallocate Crs_columns


end

end
close Crs_tbl
Deallocate Crs_tbl
```

Comment: I think you shouldn't use cursor. What's this code do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an infinite loop because you dont `FETCH NEXT` from either cursor inside of the 2nd loop, so you are always operating on the first value loaded into the cursor. So `FETCH STATUS` is always = to 0. `FETCH STATUS` only returns 1 when you try to fetch a record from the cursor and theres no more data to fetch.

You can nest cursors no problem as long as you eventually break out of your loop.